# Do Javascript mousemove event handlers block mousemove events?

Tags: javascript, events, mousemove

If I have an intensive `mousemove` handler

```
window.moveEventCounter = 0;
window.addEventHandler("mousemove", function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  window.moveEventCounter++;
});
```

the count of mousemove events handled is less than the count of events when a quick event handler is registered instead for the same (or similar) mouse action.

I figure this is the browser engine being clever about not overfilling the event queue when there's heavy execution, but it's not what I expected.

What is the browser's policy for dropping (or not emitting) mousemove events? (This behaviour was observed on Firefox 30)

Comment: How actually could you notice an event was "dropped"? What if it's not some events have been dropped but just fewer events have been emitted?

Comment: I compared the event count after the same mouse action between the two cases. I do have a feeling it is that fewer events are being "emitted" or dispatched - but it's the interactivity with Firefox that's throttling it in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser will definitely "drop" some of `mousemove` events, basically because it can't just execute your function once for each pixel the cursor has passed through. The frequency of execution depends on the browser itself:

> **The frequency rate of events while the pointing device is moved is implementation-, device-, and platform-specific**, but multiple consecutive `mousemove` events should be fired for sustained pointer-device movement, rather than a single event for each instance of mouse movement. **Implementations are encouraged to determine the optimal frequency rate to balance responsiveness with performance.**
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mousemove</sub>

Firefox would probably fire another `mousemove` event only when the last one is finished, since JavaScript is single threaded and it doesn't want to fill up the stack. You can say Firefox is "blocking" the event, but what I would say is Firefox is firing the event less frequently.

Comment: "and it doesn't want to fill up the stack" --- even if it wanted it couldn't :-)

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I can always look into Firefox source code to find out exactly what they do.

Answer (score 1):

As we all know - javascript is single threaded by its nature.

What it means is that when js code is being executed - a browser freezes. It means that whatever you "do" in the browser at that very moment - isn't handled by it, since the browser application is not responsive to the interactions.

What it means is that it's not events dropped, but it's less events emitted, since now browser spends more time executing JS instead of handling your inputs.

Comment: Your wording seems to imply that JS execution blocks mousemove events from being emitted - which is certainly not in general true. For example: `window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {console.log(e)}); while (true) {};` still logs movement events. When does a browser decide to "close its ears" to mouse movements?

Comment: @jameh: I wonder how you are testing this. I don't see any logs, the browser just freezes immediately.

Comment: @jameh - `mousemove` would never log anything because the `while` is blocking it. (Unless you create another thread..ah hem, worker)

Comment: Entering that in a Firefox console, quickly wiggling the mouse around over the DOMs, exiting the mouse from the window before the "unresponsive script" dialog opens, a single mousemove event is logged to the console on the dialog popup.